# Proxy manager to return proxy format

Tags: python-3.x

I have been working on a very simple code where I am I open a given file file which has a format of:

**proxies.txt**

```
hello:12345
hello:12345:apple:orange
test:4125
test:53953:hello:world
myserver:1337:usertest:passwordtest
```

what I want to do with these lines is that I want to return a format of e.g.

```
{'https': 'http://hello:12345:apple@orange'}
{'https': 'http://test:53953:hello@world'}
{'https': 'http://hello:12345'}
```

As we can see there is two scenarios where a line can be containing `ip:port` and `ip:port:username:password`.

```
import random
from typing import List, Dict


class ProxyManager(object):
    def __init__(self, proxy_file_path=None):
        self.proxies = self.load_proxies(proxy_file_path) if proxy_file_path else {}

    @staticmethod
    def load_proxies(proxy_file_path) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
        """
            proxy_file_path contains:

            hello:12345                          # ip:port
            hello:12345:apple:orange             # ip:port:username:password
            test:4125                            # ip:port
            test:53                              # ip:port
            myserver:1337:usertest:passwordtest # ip:port:username:password
            
        """
        with open(proxy_file_path) as proxy_file:
            proxies = []
            for proxy in proxy_file.readlines():
                split_string = proxy.strip('\n').split(':')

                proxy_string = f'{split_string[0]}:{split_string[1]}'

                # If there is 4 : in the file, that means it contains user:pass
                if len(split_string) == 4:
                    proxy_string = f'{proxy_string}:{split_string[2]}@{split_string[3]}'

                proxies.append({'https': f'http://{proxy_string}'})

            return proxies

    def random_proxy(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return random.choice(self.proxies)

    def full_list(self) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
        return self.proxies


p = ProxyManager("test.txt")
print(p.full_list())
print(p.random_proxy())
```

The application does work as intended but I wonder if there is anything I could improve, what I am mostly looking at is the function `load_proxies` where I believe the splitting could be better and probably more small mistakes I would believe.

Looking forward to get some nice review from you! You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Proxy manager to return proxy format

### Good points

The task of your code is very simple, with main good points:

- Using of the `typing` module
- Using static methods
- Using `with`-statement to operate on a file

### Documentation

Your documentation of `load_proxies` does not describe what the function does. You can also use [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html)s:

```py
@staticmethod
def load_proxies(proxy_file_path) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    """
    Parse proxies into the format `http://ip:port` or `http://ip:port:user@password`.

    >>> load_proxies(['hello:12345', 'hello:12345:apple:orange'])
    [{'https': 'http://hello:12345'}, {'https': 'http://hello:12345:apple@orange'}]
    >>> load_proxies(['test:4125', 'myserver:1337:usertest:passwordtest'])
    [{'https': 'http://test:4125'}, {'https': 'http://myserver:1337:usertest@passwordtest'}]
    """
```

---

In the class constructor, note that `proxies` will be an empty **dictionary** if `proxy_file_path` is not passed else it will be a **list** of parsed proxies. Therefore, your declaration of `full_list` is wrong if `proxy_file_path` is not passed in the constructor. [Since dictionaries can't be used inside a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1957396/9997212), just make the default value a list:

```py
class ProxyManager(object):
    def __init__(self, proxy_file_path=None):
        self.proxies = self.load_proxies(proxy_file_path) if proxy_file_path else []
```

If you want to use sets, take a look at [frozen sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8706053/9997212) and change the return type of `full_list` accordingly (and also its name!).

### Performance

When you do `proxy_file.readlines()`, you're loading *all* the file into the memory as a list. If you have a small file, it'll work well, but it may raise a MemoryError for large files. So you can replace

```py
for proxy in proxy_file.readlines():
```

with

```py
for proxy in proxy_file:
```

### Logic

Since 1) it's not an action (such as `start` or `create_proxy`) and 2) it doesn't receive arguments, you can use [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627002/9997212) instead of methods for `full_list` and `random_proxy`:

```py
@property
def random_proxy(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
    return random.choice(self.proxies)

@property
def full_list(self) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    return self.proxies
```

This allows you to call them

```py
p = ProxyManager("test.txt")
print(p.full_list)
print(p.random_proxy)
```

Beware the name of `full_list`: what if you need to change its implementation to another data structure (e.g. a set or a generator)? Existing code that called `full_list` expecting it to return a list will break. If you want, you can simply name it `proxies`.

---

Since `proxy_string` will always start with "http://", you can already initialize the string with it, replacing

```py
proxy_string = f'{split_string[0]}:{split_string[1]}'
# ...
proxies.append({'https': f'http://{proxy_string}'})
```

with

```py
proxy_string = f'http://{split_string[0]}:{split_string[1]}'
# ...
proxies.append({'https': proxy_string})
```

This allows you to evaluate one f-string instead of two.

---

Since you will always use the first two elements of `split_string`, you can use [tuple unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10532492/9997212) to make the code more readable, replacing

```py
split_string = proxy.strip('\n').split(':')
proxy_string = f'http://{split_string[0]}:{split_string[1]}'
```

with

```py
ip, port, *args = proxy.strip('\n').split(':')
proxy_string = f'http://{ip}:{port}'
```

With this, you introduce a new `args` variable: a list containing all the remaining strings from the split. So, you can check its length and add them to the `proxy_string`, replacing

```
if len(split_string) == 4:
    proxy_string = f'{proxy_string}:{split_string[2]}@{split_string[3]}'
```

with

```
if len(args) == 2:
    user, password = args
    proxy_string += f":{user}@{password}"
```

---

Note that [you're doing two tasks inside one function](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/166884/369544): creating proxies strings that can be formatted as 1) `ip:port` and 2) `ip:post:user:password`. It's up to you, but you could extract the logic into two (private) separate functions:

```py
@staticmethod
def load_proxies(proxy_file_path) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    def _load_ip_proxy(value: str) -> str:
        """
        Transform a `{ip}:{port}` string into a `http://{ip}:{port}` string.
        """
        ip, port = value.split(":")
        return f"http://{ip}:{port}"

    def _load_ipup_proxy(value: str) -> str:
        """
        Transform a `{ip}:{port}:{user}:{password}` string into a `http://{ip}:{port}:{user}@{password}` string.
        """
        ip, port, user, password = value.split(":")
        return f"http://{ip}:{port}:{user}@{password}"
    
    with open(proxy_file_path) as proxy_file:
        proxies = []
        for proxy in proxy_file:
            if proxy.count(":") == 1:
                proxies.append({'https': _load_ip_proxy(proxy.strip('\n'))})
            elif proxy.count(":") == 3:
                proxies.append({'https': _load_ipup_proxy(proxy.strip('\n'))})

            return proxies
```

A variation of the above code using Python's ["switch statements"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/103081/9997212):

```py
@staticmethod
def load_proxies(proxy_file_path) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    # ...

    # Make a dictionary holding the parsing functions according to their `:` counts
    parsing_functions = {1: _load_ip_proxy, 3: _load_ipup_proxy}

    with open(proxy_file_path) as proxy_file:
        proxies = []
        # Use `line` instead of `proxy`
        for line in proxy_file:
            # Define `proxy` here, defining the strip logic in only one place
            proxy = line.strip('\n')

            # Get the parsing function by the number of `:` in the proxy
            parsing_function = parsing_functions.get(proxy.count(":"))
            if parsing_function is None:
                # Do nothing/raise an exception if proxy does not contain
                # neither one nor three `:` characters
                continue
 
            proxies.append({'https': parsing_function(proxy)})

        return proxies
```

### Refactored code

````py
import random
from typing import List, Dict, Optional


# `class ClassName(object)` is not needed in Python 3.x
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/1203997/9997212
class ProxyManager:
    # What is the type of `proxy_file_path`? You can use Optional
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional
    def __init__(self, proxy_file_path: Optional[str] = None):
        # Make `self.proxies` virtually private by adding a `_` prefix
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641236/9997212
        self._proxies = self.load_proxies(proxy_file_path) if proxy_file_path else []

    # Is this method intended to be available to the outside world?
    # If not, make it "private" by adding a `_` prefix.
    @staticmethod
    # What's the type of `proxy_file_path`?
    def load_proxies(proxy_file_path: str) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
        """
        Parse proxies into the format `http://ip:port` or `http://ip:port:user@password`.

        >>> load_proxies(['hello:12345', 'hello:12345:apple:orange'])
        [{'https': 'http://hello:12345'}, {'https': 'http://hello:12345:apple@orange'}]
        >>> load_proxies(['test:4125', 'myserver:1337:usertest:passwordtest'])
        [{'https': 'http://test:4125'}, {'https': 'http://myserver:1337:usertest@passwordtest'}]
        """

        def _load_ip_proxy(value: str) -> str:
            """
            Transform a `{ip}:{port}` string into a `http://{ip}:{port}` string.
            """
            ip, port = value.split(":")
            return f"http://{ip}:{port}"

        def _load_ipup_proxy(value: str) -> str:
            """
            Transform a `{ip}:{port}:{user}:{password}` string into a `http://{ip}:{port}:{user}@{password}` string.
            """
            ip, port, user, password = value.split(":")
            return f"http://{ip}:{port}:{user}@{password}"
        
        parsing_functions = {1: _load_ip_proxy, 3: _load_ipup_proxy}

        with open(proxy_file_path) as proxy_file:
            proxies = []
            
            for line in proxy_file:
                proxy = line.strip('\n')

                parsing_function = parsing_functions.get(proxy.count(":"))
                if parsing_function is None:
                    continue
 
                proxies.append({'https': parsing_function(proxy)})

            return proxies

    @property
    def random_proxy(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return random.choice(self._proxies)

    @property
    def full_list(self) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
        return self._proxies

# If you import this file, this code will ALWAYS be executed, which 
# may not be intended. Add a module condition:
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/9997212
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = ProxyManager("test.txt")
    print(p.full_list)
    print(p.random_proxy)
```
````

Comment: In your refactored code you are missing the line about `parsing_functions`: For example:

`parsing_functions = {1: _load_ip_proxy, 3: _load_ipup_proxy}`

It will throw a: `NameError: name 'parsing_functions' is not defined`

Comment: Yes, I missed that, thanks!

Comment: Oh wow! I did not expected such a well code review. I feel very honored to get such a good review and also it was lots of good knowledge that I would never ever taught about at all! I have read everything multiple times and I do like the way you thought about this. Very well done and thanks for the help as well!

Answer (score 1):

## General Comments

I will second some of the @enzo comments regarding performance and logic. Additionally you will find the following observations helpful:

### Compilation error if text file contains extra empty lines

When I copy paste your code in my editor and run it with the example file that contains more than 2 extra empty lines, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/uncategorized/proxies.py", line 43, in <module>
    p = ProxyManager("test.txt")
  File "/uncategorized/proxies.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.proxies = self.load_proxies(proxy_file_path) if proxy_file_path else {}
  File "/uncategorized/proxies.py", line 26, in load_proxies
    proxy_string = f'{split_string[0]}:{split_string[1]}'
IndexError: list index out of range
```

### Returning a mutable proxy list

In the `full_list` method or property or whatever you want to use there, you are returing the original `proxies` list which is mutable by the client. This means that the client can take this list and modify it and send you for example another list:

```
def full_list(self) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    return self.proxies
...
p = ProxyManager("test.txt")
l = p.full_list()
l.pop()
l.pop()
l.pop()
l.pop()
print(p.full_list()) # prints [{'https': 'http://hello:12345'}]
l.pop()
l.append({'https': 'http://goodbye:12345'})
print(p.full_list())  # prints [{'https': 'http://goodbye:12345'}]
```

This is not good if you want to just return something that the client cannot interfere with. Instead you should either return a frozen set or a copy of the `proxies` list.

### Method `random_proxy` breaks if `proxy_file_path` is empty

This breaks in @enzo answer as well. When you create a new instance of `ProxyManager` without specifying the `proxy_file_path` then calling the `random_proxy` subsequently will throw an error:

```py
p = ProxyManager()
print(p.random_proxy()) # Throws KeyError: 0
```

You should always check if the proxy list has been initialized before usage:

```
def random_proxy(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
   return random.choice(self.proxies) if len(self.proxies) > 0 else {}
```

### Catch exception when opening file

It doesn't hurt to catch an exception when opening files when they do not exist. I will let [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713794/catching-an-exception-while-using-a-python-with-statement) explain it better.

Comment: Hello Fanis! Thank you so much for the help as well as I saw you commented @enzo as well. Both was very well written and I do see the improvements you have mentioned as well. However I was not able to reproduce the `Compilation error if text file contains extra empty lines` unless I did something wrong but I added 4 new lines after the last one and it never threw any error. Also do appreciate the review you gave and I agree. The catch exception is something I just added while I read ur review. You both are awesome! <3