# Availability of proxies

Tags: python-3.x

I have previously got a review of something similar (but not the same but its related to proxies) which can be found via: [proxy-manager-to-return-proxy-format](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/266276/proxy-manager-to-return-proxy-format/266296#266296)

What I am now trying to do is that I want to lock the proxies when they are in use. When they are in use we block them and whenever they are finished with they supposed to do then another thread can pick it up. I have ended up doing something like this **See AvailableProxies()** as **ProxyManager** has been reviewed:

```
import random
import threading
import time
from typing import List, Dict, Optional

from loguru import logger

"""
Been reviewed: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/266293/223687
"""


class ProxyManager:
    def __init__(self, proxy_file_path: Optional[str] = None):
        self._proxies = self._load_proxies(proxy_file_path) if proxy_file_path else []

    @staticmethod
    def _load_proxies(proxy_file_path: str) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
        """
        Parse proxies into the format `http://ip:port` or `http://ip:port:user@password`.
        #
        >> load_proxies(['hello:12345', 'hello:12345:apple:orange'])
        # [{'https': 'http://hello:12345'}, {'https': 'http://hello:12345:apple@orange'}]
        >> load_proxies(['test:4125', 'myserver:1337:usertest:passwordtest'])
        [{'https': 'http://test:4125'}, {'https': 'http://myserver:1337:usertest@passwordtest'}]
        """

        def _load_ip_proxy(value: str) -> str:
            """
            Transform a `{ip}:{port}` string into a `http://{ip}:{port}` string.
            """
            ip, port = value.split(":")
            return f"http://{ip}:{port}"

        def _load_ipup_proxy(value: str) -> str:
            """
            Transform a `{ip}:{port}:{user}:{password}` string into a `http://{ip}:{port}:{user}@{password}` string.
            """
            ip, port, user, password = value.split(":")
            return f"http://{ip}:{port}:{user}@{password}"

        parsing_functions = {1: _load_ip_proxy, 3: _load_ipup_proxy}

        with open(proxy_file_path) as proxy_file:
            proxies = []

            for line in proxy_file:
                proxy = line.strip('\n')

                parsing_function = parsing_functions.get(proxy.count(":"))
                if parsing_function is None:
                    continue

                proxies.append({'https': parsing_function(proxy)})

            return proxies

    @property
    def random_proxy(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return random.choice(self._proxies) if len(self._proxies) > 0 else {}

    @property
    def full_list(self) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
        return self._proxies


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proxies path
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
proxies: Dict[str, ProxyManager] = {
    "rotating": ProxyManager("./proxies/rotating.txt"),
    "test": ProxyManager("./proxies/test.txt")
}

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proxies available
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
all_proxies = [proxy['https'] for proxy in proxies["test"].full_list]
proxy_dict = dict(zip(all_proxies, [True] * len(all_proxies)))

proxy_lock: threading = threading.Lock()


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Initialize availability of proxies
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
class AvailableProxies:
    def __enter__(self):
        proxy_lock.acquire()
        self.proxy = None

        while not self.proxy:
            if available := [att for att, value in proxy_dict.items() if value]:
                self.proxy = random.choice(available)
                proxy_dict[self.proxy] = False
            else:
                logger.info("Waiting ... no proxies available")
                time.sleep(.2)

        proxy_lock.release()
        return self.proxy

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        proxy_dict[self.proxy] = True
```

To be able to test it:

```
import threading
import threading
import time

from lib.proxies import AvailableProxies


def main(thread_name):
    while True:
        with AvailableProxies() as proxies:
            print(f"Thread name: {thread_name} -> {proxies}")
            time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        threading.Thread(target=main, args=(i,)).start()
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

However there is some script where I will use that I will not use the `AvailableProxies` and only `ProxyManager` (But the `AvailableProxies` should be available to import at any time to my scripts of course :) (If thats matters)

There is somethings I am concern about is that I am not sure if this method to set a proxy to "available" and "busy" is a valid way to do (but hey, it works!).

I am looking forward for any code review and I do hope this time I will not get shocked as I got on my previous review :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Availability of proxies

### Documentation

The `threading` name refers to the module, the `threading.Lock` name refers to a class inside that module. Thus, the type of `proxy_lock` is wrong, since it's an instance of `threading.Lock`. You can replace it with

```
proxy_lock: threading.Lock = threading.Lock()
```

### Performance

To avoid allocating a list filled with `True`s, you can use [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) and replace

```py
proxy_dict = dict(zip(all_proxies, [True] * len(all_proxies)))
```

with

```py
proxy_dict = dict.fromkeys(all_proxies, True)
```

### Logic

You can use a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement) to use your lock. There are two main advantages of using a context manager:

1. You'll only use your `proxy_lock` variable once, in the with-block. Currently, you're using twice and it may be prone to errors (e.g. you may change your code in the future and accidentally delete the line where you release the lock).
2. If an error occurs between the lock acquire and the lock release, your lock will not be released. However, the context manager of the `threading.Lock` class will handle it for you in its internals.

So you can replace

```py
def __enter__(self):
    proxy_lock.acquire()
   
    # ...

    proxy_lock.release()
    return self.proxy
```

with

```py
def __enter__(self):
    with proxy_lock:
        # ...

    return self.proxy
```

---

The `proxy_lock` variable should not be available to the outside world, only `AvailableProxies` will use it. However, when you import `lib.proxies`, `proxy_lock` will come with it. You can make it a private class attribute:

```py
class AvailableProxies:
    _proxy_lock: threading.Lock = threading.Lock()

    def __enter__(self):
        with self._proxy_lock:
            # ...

        return self.proxy
```

#### Dependency injection

You should decide whether or not to use dependency injection. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/131766/9997212) explains it well:

> Dependency Injection is a practice where objects are designed in a manner where they receive instances of the objects from other pieces of code, instead of constructing them internally. This means that any object implementing the interface which is required by the object can be substituted in without changing the code, which simplifies testing, and improves decoupling.

Its main goal is to make unit testing easier and one of its rules is to "avoid using mutable global variables". Your `proxy_dict` variable is mutable and it's declared in the outermost (global) scope, thus it's against the principles of DI. Think if it's worth it. If it is, here's how to fix it step-by-step:

1. Note that, in your driver file, `main` is creating an instance of `AvailableProxies`. Let's use DI and pass the dependency to `main` instead of creating a new one:

```
def main(manager, thread_name):
    while True:
        with manager as proxies:
            print(f"Thread name: {thread_name} -> {proxies}")
            time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Only one instance
    manager = AvailableProxies()

    for i in range(10):
        threading.Thread(target=main, args=(manager, i)).start()
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

You can try this change. You'll notice that it will not work: only threads 0-4 will get a proxy, threads 5-9 will [deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34512/9997212) on `self.proxy` since there's only one instance of `AvailableProxies`. We can fix this by using [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) instead of using `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

I also like using  the latter, but in this case `__exit__` needs to access the proxy found by `__enter__`, and the only way for `__enter__` pass it to `__exit__` is by creating a instance variable (thus modifying the instance). However, `contextlib.contextmanager` allows this transfer to occur via a local variable, which does not modify the instance and removes the deadlock threat:

```
import contextlib

class AvailableProxies:
    # ...

    @property
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def proxies(self):
        # Note that we can use `proxy` instead of `self.proxy`
        # Since our goal is to use only one instance of `AvailableProxies`
        # and multiple threads, using a local variable here don't modify 
        # the instance in any way, avoiding a possible deadlock
        proxy = None

        with self._proxy_lock:
            while not proxy:
                if available := [att for att, value in proxy_dict.items() if value]:
                    proxy = random.choice(available)
                    proxy_dict[proxy] = False
                else:
                    logger.info("Waiting ... no proxies available")
                    time.sleep(.2)

        yield proxy

        proxy_dict[proxy] = True
```

In your driver file:

```
def main(manager, thread_name):
    while True:
        # Access the `proxies` property here
        with manager.proxies as proxies:
            print(f"Thread name: {thread_name} -> {proxies}")
            time.sleep(3)
```

This now works as expected.

2. The `proxy_dict` dictionary is still mutable and it's still global. Let's create it in the constructor of `AvailableProxies` as a instance variable:

```py
class AvailableProxies:
    # ...

    # Pass the proxies as a dependency to the constructor (DI)
    def __init__(self, proxies: Dict[str, ProxyManager]):
        all_proxies = [proxy['https'] for proxy in proxies["test"].full_list]
        self._proxy_dict = dict.fromkeys(all_proxies, True)
 
    @property
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def proxies(self):
        # Replace `proxy_dict` here with `self._proxy_dict`
        ...
```

You may ask here: when I do `self._proxy_dict[proxy] = True`, I'm modifying the `AvailableProxies` instance, why doesn't a deadlock occur here too? The answer is that the loop inside the lock does not depend on `self._proxy_dict`, but depended on `self.proxy`. If you modified `self.proxy`, it would affect the loop condition, creating the deadlock. Since the loop doesn't depend on `self._proxy_dict`, you can modify it fine.

Since now `AvailableProxies` expects `proxies` as an argument to its constructor, create `proxies` as a local variable instead of a global variable:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    proxies: Dict[str, ProxyManager] = {
        "rotating": ProxyManager("./proxies/rotating.txt"),
        "test": ProxyManager("./proxies/test.txt")
    }

    manager = AvailableProxies(proxies)
    for i in range(10):
        threading.Thread(target=main, args=(manager, i)).start()
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

Your code is fine now: no more global variables.

---

For a final note, I would suggest to add a suffix to `AvailableProxies`, such as `AvailableProxiesProvider` or `AvailableProxiesManager`, but that's up to you.

Comment: Once again a hero! Oh wow, I honestly cant believe how you managed to change my code totally but also describing every step why and how which I really love. I have read the answer already 5 times and have adapted it into my code. It is indeed very well written. thank you so much! I do indeed have a question. Is it okey to have the `manager = AvailableProxies(proxies)` in a utils.py lib and then just import it to a scripts where you basically want to use it? (e.g. test1.py and test2.py imports `from lib.utils import manager` instead of doing it in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` ?

Comment: Yes, it's okay! In fact, the approach you mentioned is [the easiest way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6760821/9997212) of creating [a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/137975/9997212) in Python.

Comment: Thank you so much Enzo! I wish you a very good day, week, month, years and all coming years ahead! You are awesome!